# SQL Server Linked Server query returns empty rows

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server

I use SQL Server 2014. I have setup a linked server via ODBC to a legacy database system. When I run this query:

```
select * 
from openquery([MyLink], 'select Ref, FxRate from <table> where Ref=155003')
```

I get the result with the correct number of records and columns.

But the values are all defaults:

```
Ref  FxRate
  0       0
```

In the table there are actual numbers for this. I was able to do a linked server for this same database from another server. I have tried to replicate that the best I could. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT Ref, FxRate FROM LinkedServer.DataBase.schema.table WHERE Ref = 155003`?

Comment: Yeah but that gave the same result.

Comment: So, whatever you use OPENQUERY, linked_server.database.schema.table you get same zeros in output? Can you run this query directly on this server?

Comment: I could and the server used to return all the data. I updated with answer. Thank you for trying to help me. This took a day of my life.

Comment: Great, that you solve it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting this answer here for others. The ODBC driver was incompatible with the new machine's OS. I arrived at this conclusion after verifying that the correct query was executing on the legacy database but only the results were not display properly (they were all blanked out). I then ruled out any encoding issues. And finally upgraded the ODBC driver which fixed it.